# Checking for input's state via css

Tags: css, web, sass

Pretty simple question (I think), is there a way to write a conditional statement checking for an inputs state using only css? I'm trying to write one checking if it's :checked or not.

I should have elaborated a little bit more. I'm messing around with two inputs, one is withing a sibling list to the first I'm attempting to change a property on the first input once the second has been checked. Just wondering if anyone has found a way to do this with the assumption that the answer will be "no".

```
<nav>
        <label for="menu-toggle" class="openMenu"><span></span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>

        <ul id="main-menu">
            <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <label for="menu-toggle-2" class="openDrop">
                        <a name=Services>Services</a>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-2"/>
                 <ul id="drop">
                    <li><a href=#>blah</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>blah</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>blah</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href=#>Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

</nav>
```

I do know how to do this with JS, just am messing around to see if it's possible in any way with just css.

Comment: You do understand that Sass code is never sent to the client, right?  Whatever you're asking for has to be a feature of CSS.

Comment: Yes i do realize that. I was trying to get what i'm doing working in just css, but couldn't. Therefore, I figured writing a conditional in sass that would then compile into css would be easier to figure out and work with.

Comment: Why would that work out easier?  If you don't know what CSS is necessary to get the intended results, Sass can't help you.

Comment: I changed the title to appease you a bit more haha. I understand what you are saying, I am not new that new to sass. I just assumed that, logically, it might be easier to write using sass than css.

Comment: `<input>` elements are *void elements*, how exactly is "*one...a child of the other*"? And no: until CSS gets a parent, or subject/`:has()`, selector this won't be possible.

Comment: You're right haha, i honestly don't know why I referred to it as that, just a rushed day i suppose. I'll post the html so you can see what i am saying. Its a child of the sibling Ul rather.

That was what i figured though, that without some sort of parent selector it isn't possible. Just wanted to check before i move on as i have seen some very creative things accomplished using pure css.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

SASS is just a superset of CSS, and is compiled to CSS before sent to the browser. Therefore, as CSS, it cannot do any 'conditional statements' - it's simply not a programming language but a declarative language.

Having said that, acting on 'checked' behaviour [is pretty trivial](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/kxa88o68/). I used this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"><span></span>
```

With this CSS:

```
input + span:before {
    content:'Not Checked';
}
input:checked + span:before {
    content:'Checked!';
}
```

This is just generic CSS though and has nothing to do with SASS, nor can it be improved through SASS.